# How do you create a stream in a native c++ node module

Tags: c++, node.js

I have a native node module that manipulates some data and should stream it to the browser. But, I'm having a hard time finding how to do that in C++.

Am I supposed to manually create and manage my own libuv pipe? Or is there a better node wrapper that I'm not aware of?

So far, I've found the imagemagick-native module does the former, but I hope that isn't the only option.

Comment: Why not do the streaming in javascript-land and use your addon's data manipulation function(s) inside your streaming code?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to node. Is there a way to go C++ -> server-side js -> client-side js without one step blocking until  it gets an EOF? I've written C++ code that respects the pipeline, but adding that intermediary server-side js can be done without waiting for the full output? If there were a way to have node just open a file descriptor for my C++ code to write to, that would be my prefered way to do it and let node/v8 manage the network on its own.

Comment: Hi!
I wanted to do something like this and I was searching for it.
Did you find anything?